# How to flag rows with a max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ID that identify each of my rows, a article_ID, a supplier_ID and a stock.

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------+
| ID | article_ID | supplier_ID | stock |
+----+------------+-------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          | 1           | 18    |
| 2  | 1          | 2           | 1     |
| 3  | 1          | 3           | 20    |
| 4  | 2          | 1           | 5     |
| 5  | 2          | 2           | 40    |
| 6  | 3          | 1           | 56    |
| 7  | 3          | 3           | 7     |
| 8  | 3          | 4           | 12    |
+----+------------+-------------+-------+
```

I need to flag the supplier that provide the maximum stock and get the following result :

```
+----+------------+-------------+-------+------+
| ID | article_ID | supplier_ID | stock | flag |
+----+------------+-------------+-------+------+
| 1  | 1          | 1           | 18    | 0    |
| 2  | 1          | 2           | 1     | 0    |
| 3  | 1          | 3           | 20    | 1    |
| 4  | 2          | 1           | 5     | 0    |
| 5  | 2          | 2           | 40    | 1    |
| 6  | 3          | 1           | 56    | 1    |
| 7  | 3          | 3           | 7     | 0    |
| 8  | 3          | 4           | 12    | 0    |
+----+------------+-------------+-------+------+
```

My understanding of the problem is that I need to make a select from a select where I identify the max stock value row ID, but I don't know how to get there.
I'm stuck... need your help stackoverflow's knights!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when stock = max(stock) over (partition by article_id)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Note:  This will flag multiple suppliers, if they all have the same maximum.  If you want only one, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by article_id order by stock desc) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT t.*, (CASE WHEN t.stock = t1.maxstock THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flag
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(t1.stock) as maxstock 
      FROM table t1
      WHERE t1.article_id = t.article_id
     ) t1;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this will help you.

```
                create table #temp

            (
            ID int,
            article_ID int,
            supplier_ID int,
            stock int
            )

            insert into #temp values (1  , 1 , 1, 18)
            insert into #temp values (2  , 1          , 2           , 1    )
            insert into #temp values (3  , 1          , 3           , 20   )
            insert into #temp values (4  , 2          , 1           , 5    )
            insert into #temp values (5  , 2          , 2           , 40   )
            insert into #temp values (6  , 3          , 1           , 56   )
            insert into #temp values (7  , 3          , 3           , 7    )
            insert into #temp values (8  , 3          , 4           , 12   )



            Select ID,article_ID,supplier_ID,stock,case when Stock >= 20 Then 1 Else 0 End As Flag from #temp

            Drop table #temp
```

[image]

Comment: but why dear @Tony

Comment: Insert into #temp values (9, 4, 1, 1)

Comment: It won't work correctly because you set the flag for any row where the stock is greater than 20, and not where that row has the maximum value of the stock for that article_id.